# CATransaction completion block being called immediately when animation is added to subview

Tags: ios, swift, caanimation

I'm trying to start animation on the newly added UIImageView as subview but it seems that completion block is called immediately in this case even though animations are added after the CATransaction.setCompletionBlock

```
addSubview(imageView)

CATransaction.begin()

let posAnimation = positionAnimation(startPoint: startPoint, endPoint: endPoint, beginTime: beginTime, duration: duration)
let alpAnimation = alphaAnimation(beginTime: beginTime, duration: duration)

CATransaction.setCompletionBlock{ [weak self] in
print("deleting view")
//imageView.removeFromSuperview()
}

imageView.layer.add(posAnimation, forKey: nil)
imageView.layer.add(alpAnimation, forKey: nil)

CATransaction.commit()
```

Animations:

```
private func positionAnimation(startPoint: CGPoint, endPoint:CGPoint, beginTime: CFTimeInterval, duration: CFTimeInterval) -> CAKeyframeAnimation {
    let positionAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")

    positionAnimation.path = customPath(middlePoint: startPoint, endPoint: endPoint).cgPath
    positionAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    positionAnimation.duration = duration
    positionAnimation.beginTime = beginTime
    positionAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    return positionAnimation
}

private func alphaAnimation(beginTime: CFTimeInterval, duration: CFTimeInterval) -> CAKeyframeAnimation {
    let alphaAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    alphaAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    alphaAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    alphaAnimation.values = [1.0, 1.0, 0.0]
    alphaAnimation.keyTimes = [0.0,0.5,1.0]
    alphaAnimation.duration = duration
    alphaAnimation.beginTime = beginTime
    return alphaAnimation
}
```

Any idea why is it not working?

Comment: What are the values of `beginTime` and `duration`?

Comment: duration = 1 and beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 1

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the animation is not on the rendering tree. i.e. the view has no `superView`. or somewhere its `superView` has no `superView`. You may need to check whether the view implementing functions was added to a `window` or `view` somewhere.

Comment: I am adding the `imageView` directly to the `view` of `UIViewController` long after `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: so the view is customized subclass of UIView? what's the type of this view and where do you implement the addSubView(imageView)